# Issue with JPA join column with null value

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to establish the one to one relationship between two table `Master` and `Groups`, below is the association is defined with Groups.

```
Class: Master
```

I am joining with 3 columns with Groups table and one of the column can be a null, when JPA generates the query,  for the null value field , check is not valid as it check with `=` operator rather than `is null` check.

What is happening is when the `SUBGRP` value is `null` it checks `SUBGRP = null` which is invalid for `null` checks

What I am expecting for when the value is `null` check it should use SUBGRP is NULL. because when I am querying sql with `SUBGRP =null` it doesn't not return any data but when I change it to `SUBGRP` is `null` i get the data.

```
JPA GENERATED QUERY: (added here only where condition)

where grpNm=? and subgrp=? and pkg=? 
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind:65 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [111111]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind:53 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind:65 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [888]


@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name = "GRPNM", referencedColumnName = "GRPNM", updatable=false, insertable=false),
@JoinColumn(name = "SUBGRP", referencedColumnName = "SUBGRP", updatable=false, insertable=false, nullable = true),
@JoinColumn(name = "PKG", referencedColumnName = "PKG", updatable=false, insertable=false)
})
protected Group group;
```

Can any one suggest me how resolve this issue when one of the join column is `null` and it should do `is null` rather `= null` check?

Comment: Tried @Nullabe? Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html)